# "is" operator works differently in Immediate Window for boxed values

Tags: c#, types, visual-studio-debugging

For a boxed `int`, e.g. `object boxedInt = 0` defined in your code, both `is object` and `is int` return `false` in Visual Studio's Immediate Window. This is a bug, isn't it?

Code:

```
int normalInt = 0;

Debug.WriteLine(normalInt.GetType().FullName); // System.Int32
Debug.WriteLine(normalInt is object);          // true
Debug.WriteLine(normalInt is int);             // true
Debug.WriteLine(normalInt is System.Int32);    // true

object boxedInt = 0;

Debug.WriteLine(boxedInt.GetType().FullName); // System.Int32
Debug.WriteLine(boxedInt is object);          // true
Debug.WriteLine(boxedInt is int);             // true
Debug.WriteLine(boxedInt is System.Int32);    // true
```

Immediate Window:

```
normalInt.GetType().FullName
"System.Int32"
normalInt is object
true
normalInt is int
true
normalInt is System.Int32
true

boxedInt.GetType().FullName
"System.Int32"
boxedInt is object
false                                         // WTF?
boxedInt is int
false                                         // WTF?
boxedInt is System.Int32
false                                         // WTF?

object boxedInt2 = 0;
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
boxedInt2.GetType().FullName
"System.Int32"
boxedInt2 is object
true
boxedInt2 is int
true
boxedInt2 is System.Int32
true
```

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Version 15.3.3
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.3+26730.12

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

Visual C# 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA135

---

Screenshot with `Watch` window:

[image]

Comment: Yes. E.g., when setting a breakpoint after the above code.

Comment: I think you have to do- `boxedInt == typeof(object);`

Comment: @SouvikGhosh `boxedInt` in't a `Type` object, so that will never be true.

Comment: @Sinatr `is` *doesn't* need a type on the left side.  If you use the `==` operator to compare something to a `Type` then *that* is when you need to have a `Type`.

Comment: I think this is due to the sandbox that the Immediate Window runs in.  The `Object` from the window isn't the same `Type` as the `Object` from the application, even though the full name is the same.  If you do `typeof(Object) == (boxedInt.GetType())` in the Immediate Window, it returns false.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: typeof(Object) == (boxedInt.GetType()) is false, of course, because boxedInt is an int. However, having both typeof(int) == (boxedInt.GetType()) == true and boxedInt is int == false is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Under Tools->Option->Debugging, please enable option "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators", debug it again.

[image]

Update:

The issue has been reported here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31283/and-operation-of-boolean-is-wrong.html

Comment: This is a helpful answer as it works indeed. However, it does not answer why you would want the observed behavior in non-legacy (i.e. supposed to be better) mode and whether that may be a bug. I vote this up but do not accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Marco Eckstein, I will report this issue and discuss with other members, if I get any latest information, I will share it here.

Comment: @Marco Eckstein, The similar issue has been reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31283/and-operation-of-boolean-is-wrong.html, product team members will follow up it, you could also share your comment there.